# Unity game objects' Type evaluating to a "null" string literal, even though the object is not actually null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my current Unity (5.x) code-base, game objects' `Type` (in C#) are showing up as a string `"null"` when debugging.

The properties are actually valid and the object is instantiated, it's just Unity is somehow assigning this string of `"null"` when evaluating their `Type` in the debugger.

The kicker is, `if(mCurrentItem == null)` in my example below actually evaluates to true, even though it's definitely not actually null (which defies all of my knowledge of .NET)... this isn't javascript, where `"null" == null`, so why is .NET evaluating this to true?

[image]

Comment: What type is `mCurrentItem`? Maybe it overloads the `==` operator.

Comment: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/ This may give a hint on what Unity does on the back. It is for GameObject type but there may be some related issue to other types. This one too http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/fun-with-null.148090/